# Sorting by some column and also by rand() in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

Is it possible to sort a result set by some column and also by RAND()?

For example:

```
  SELECT `a`, `b`, `c` 
    FROM `table` 
ORDER BY `a` DESC, RAND() 
   LIMIT 0, 10
```

Thank you.

Comment: The query provided will run - it will sort by column `a` in DESCending order.  Columns `b` and `c` will be random...  Is that what your question is?

Comment: Not quite. I would like to sort the entire result set by date (DESC) and by RAND().

Comment: You can't sort by two things at the same time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920574/how-to-select-order-by-column-and-rand-both

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are doing is valid - it will order the results in descending order by `a` but randomize the order of ties.

However to do what you want you need to first use a subquery to get the latest 100 records and then afterwards sort the results of that subquery randomly using an outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM table1
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 100
) T1
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Comment: Mark, the output isn't as I expected.

Comment: Ties aren't randomized when using `ORDER BY col, RAND()`

Comment: Mark, this is not what I want. I want to be able to get the latest (so sorted by date DESC) 100 entries sorted by rand().

Comment: @Psyche: Nothing. It's an alias for the derived table (sub query). You can write something else if you prefer - such as `most_recent_rows` or `i_like_unicorns`.

Comment: @MarkByers just to add here, if result set of inner query has all unique dates then using RAND() is redundant as it will have no effect at all. In other words, sorting by column with unique values and then sorting by RAND() is useless (rather cost extra useless work).

Comment: For me, this approach (nested SELECT with `LIMIT` then `ORDER BY RAND()`) works a bit faster than using single `SELECT` and is as *quick as plain query* without randomization at all. I tried it with `LIMIT 200`.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but I discovered ... Example:

> select photo.sort_order,
>          profile.description is not null as desc_order,
>          profile.description,
>          rand() as r
>   from
>          photo photo, profile profile
>   order by 
>          photo.sort_order desc, 
>          desc_order desc, 
>          r ASC