# How to select ORDER BY column and RAND() both?

Tags: mysql, select, random, sql-order-by

Hello dear friends.

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tb_table ORDER BY num ASC, ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

is this coding correct?
I want to find all rows ASC num and there can be 1000 rows that num is 1 another 1000 that num is 2.
But I want it to sort ASC like 1s firstly and choose one of them randomly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You only need to specify `ORDER BY` once.

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tb_table ORDER BY num ASC, RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Is this SQL efficient? Or does introducing RAND() make it much slower?