# peewee library, sort combination

Tags: python, peewee

Consider I have table `Customer` where first field - points collected, any other field - information:

```
Points | Info
1        ...
2        ...
2        ...
1        ...
0        ...
0        ...
1        ...
```

Is there is a way I can apply descending order, then limit (by 3 for example), then apply random order on what left. Formally: `descending order -> limit -> random`.

Comment: This is not really a peewee question. This is more of a general SQL question. But also, if your result set is so small, can't you just handle the randomization in python?

Comment: I would do this, but I need to apply modifications later in the code. If I do like you said, I'll have convert to tuples, then search back in database for each entry I want to modify.
P.S. I already found [solution in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990439/sorting-by-some-column-and-also-by-rand-in-mysql), but it's hard to translate this to peewee. Also I know about subquery existence, yet I don't know how to use it so it works

Comment: Why would you have to convert to tuples? Just modify the objects directly and call save().